# How can I create a TextAppearance uses a smaller font size than @android:attr/textAppearanceSmall

Tags: android

I am trying to create my own text appearance by following this

http://brainflush.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/understanding-android-themes-and-styles/

I just want my text appearance style which inherits every thing @android:attr/textAppearanceSmall except it uses a smaller size than attr/textAppearanceSmall

So I did this:

```
<resource>
  <style name="MyDefaultTextAppearance" parent="@android:attr/textAppearanceSmall">
    <item name="android:textSize">10sp</item>
  </style>

</resources>
```

My question is what is the textSize for textAppearanceSmall for tablet? I just want to use a size smaller than android default text size for textAppearanceSmall. I am not sure if textSize 10sp is the right answer.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you checkout the SDK folder, you can find that there is no seperate `TextAppearance` style defined for tablets. I checked the `android-14` folder but couldnt find seperate entries for `large` screens. Please do search for yourself. You can find the resources in `\android-sdk\platforms\android-14\data\res`